# Checking if active layer is GeoPackage using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, pyqgis-3, geopackage

Is there a PyQGIS way to check if an active layer `iface.activeLayer()` is not a GeoPackage format?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```py
if iface.activeLayer().storageType() != 'GPKG':
    print('Active layer is not a GeoPackage format')
```